# WordPess: WooCommerce, описание продукта, поехала верстка

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет,

Такая проблема:

В самом коде ничего не менял напрямую, игрался с правым sidebar, только через WYSIWYG-инструменты админки WP без редактирования PHP/CSS/HTML.

Что-то пошло не так и описание начало съезжать

**Как у меня:**
http://puuvarasto.fi/product/osb-1-levy-1220x2440mm-paksuus-12mm/

**Как должно быть:**
http://live-demo.wooskins.com/themes/ws-wood/?product=bolivar-royal-corona

Буду благодарен за помощь в любом формате - готовое решние/мысли в какую сторону копать/предложение услуги по исправлению на платной основе.

Answer (score 1):

Если сравнить код, то выглядит так, что Вы указали не тот шаблон страницы, у Вас стоит шаблон без сайдбара при этом сайдбар включен (у тега body стоит класс `no-sidebar`, и для элемента `.entry-content` присваиваются ненужные свойства, в оригинале нет этого класса)
Посмотрите документацию к шаблону как указать шаблон или настроить страницу.

Comment: Greg, огромное Вам спасибо! Это и стало решением моей проблемы.